# How to wrap text around a landscape table over multiple pages? \sidewaystable or \landscape + \longtable

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable, rotating, landscape

I am trying to create a landscape table that breaks over multiple pages. I have successfully done this with the following code:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth{some columns}
\caption[my caption]{my caption}
table code here
\end{longtabu}
\end{landscape}
```

This does almost everything I want. I insert this code in my desired section of my document.

The problem is that the text breaks for the `landscape` environment. I have a paragraph at the top of the page and then because I inserted my table code after this paragraph, the rest of the page is blank, and then on the next pages is my landscape table. I want the text to go until the end of its page and then the `landscape` environment to run its thing for my table.

The text will wrap if the `\begin{landscape}` is changed to `\begin{sidewaystable}`. However, `sidewaystable` will not break over multiple pages; it does not allow a `longtable` or `longtabu` to work.

So sideways table won't allow a longtable and landscape won't allow text wrapping.

I've searched around on here and on Google but most of the solutions are suggesting to use either `sidewaystable` or `landscape`. However, none of the solutions really address my specific problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to proceed?

I wish I could show an image but I'm not allowed to post one as a new user.

Comment: To show an image just upload it as normal but remove the `!` from the markup. someone with edit privilege will fix it up so that the image shows.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are feeling brave you can use the `afterpage` package and go

```
\afterpage{\begin{landscape}.....\end{landscape}}
```

If the table is big (or it has any verbatim material) it is better to put it in a separate file `mytable.tex` and then just have

```
 \afterpage{\input{mytable}}
```

this isn't a real float but it does delay starting the table until the next page break.

Comment: Simple. Works. This is perfect. Thanks David!