# Using afterpage with IEEEtran documentclass

Tags: tables, page-breaking, ieeetran, landscape, afterpage

I have got an issue with using the `\afterpage` command in combination with the IEEEtran document class. I have got a large table that I want to put on a landscape page and let the other text 'wrap around' that table as suggested [here on stack exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64202/how-to-wrap-text-around-a-landscape-table-over-multiple-pages-sidewaystable-or/64203). However, using `\afterpage{\input{table.tex}}` does not put the landscape page with the table after a page is done, but after the first 'column' is done, so to say. For clarification I added an image [image: Image of the problem where \afterpage{\input{table.tex}} does not input the landscape table after the whole page is full]

My desired formatting is shown in this picture, where the table is put after a fully filled page
[image: Desired formatting]

Other variantions of the commands that I have tried

- `\afterpage{\clearpage \input{table.tex}}`
- `\afterpage{\newpage\input{table.tex}}`
- `\afterpage{\clearpage} \afterpage{\input{table.tex}}`

I think I am unaware of how some aspects of the IEEE and afterpage package work.

This is my file in which I include all packages

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10 pt]{IEEEtran} 

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}      

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{1.8 cm}
\addtolength{\headsep}{.2 cm}

\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{units} 

\usepackage{dsfont,latexsym,cite, comment, graphicx,color}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{url, hyperref}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\newcommand{\goodgap}{%for subfigure package
\hspace{\subfigtopskip}%
\hspace{\subfigbottomskip}}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{threeparttable,booktabs,makecell}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdflscape,afterpage}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\input{tikz_layout}

\def\sectionautorefname{Section}
\def\subsectionautorefname{Subsection}
\def\subsubsectionautorefname{Subsubsection}
```

This is my file in which I have the table that I want to put on a landscape page. Note, I have removed the contents

```
\begin{landscape}

\begin{center}

\begin{table}[t]
\resizebox{1\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{threeparttable}

\begin{tabular}{M{2.5cm} M{3cm} M{4cm} M{3.5cm} M{2.5cm} M{3.5cm} M{4cm} M{1.2cm} M{1.0cm}} \toprule

%% TABLE CONTENTS %%
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 

\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize

%% ITEMS %%


\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
}

\end{table}

\end{center}
\end{landscape}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: the afterpage package documentation explicitly states that it does not work in two column mode (and even in one column mode is somewhat speculative and I'd be wary of using it in a published document)

Comment: Try `\makeatletter\afterpage{\if@firstcolumn\input{...}\else\afterpage{\input{...}}\fi}\makeatother`  You might want to use \onecolumn and \twocolumn around the landscape.

Comment: It would probably be easier to use sidewaystable (rotating package) or even a table* [p] with \rotatebox (graphicx package) and a minipage.

Comment: @JohnKormylo this works, great! Thanks for your input. using \onecolumn was not necessary for it to work, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to John Kormylo

Using
`\makeatletter\afterpage{\if@firstcolumn \else\afterpage{\input{table.tex}}\fi}\makeatother` will yield the desired result