# Positioning a section with long table

Tags: positioning, longtable, landscape

I'm writing a research paper. Between two sections, there is a **Landscape Longtable**. Organized in the following way:

```
Section1(Method)
Landscape Longtable
Section2(Discussion)
```

After section1, there is a gap, then in a fresh new landscape page, the Longtable started. Then section2 started on another fresh new page. **Is there any other way to reduce the gap before longtable?** I don't want to put the table after discussion/ in the middle of the discussion.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please provide working MWE so that we can help you.

Comment: How did you rotate the table to a landscape orientation? `\begin{landscape}` always starts a new page right where it is used in the code.

Comment: How long is the "Methods"  section? Probably you can place the longtable inside of that section so you get part of the "methods" section, your longtable, then the rest of the "methods"  section together with the beginning of the "discussion"  section.

Comment: @leandriis Method section is too long, but it ended up with a table. I used `pdflatex` for landscape.

Comment: Yes, I did it using landscape,
`\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}llccl@{}}
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}`

Should I break the method section where it finished a page and put the table immediately after that? Is it wise to do so?

Comment: @Saif: You could either do that or take a look at the `afterpage` package. See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64203/134144

Comment: The `afterpage` route definitely looks to be very promising.